# Validate value of inner kery in php arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to check and get the value of a inner key of array?
It is easy explainable but impossible to realize!

So with few words,

I have multilevel arrays like: `ARRAY ( 1KEY ARRAY ( 2KEY => 2VAL, 3KEY = 3VAL ) )`

I need to check if `2KEY` exists and what `value` it has!

Here is the code im working on:

```
<?php

$array = array
  (
    "first.php" => array
                    (
                      "edit" => "0",
                      "add" => "1",
                      "delete" => "0",
                    ),
    "second.php" => array
                    (
                      "edit" => "1",
                      "add" => "1",
                      "delete" => "1",
                    )
  );
//This checks the current page that we are if it exists in array,
if (isset($array[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']])) {

    //Pass permissions into variables
    $allowEdit = isset($array['edit'])?"1":"0";
    $allowAdd = isset($array['add'])?"1":"0";
    $allowDelete = isset($array['delete'])?"1":"0";

} else {
    echo "This page don't exist!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PHP7+ you could use the null coalescing operator [`??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). Note that you will need to take the [`basename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to ensure that the lookup works:

```
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$allowEdit = $array[$page]['edit'] ?? 0;
$allowAdd = $array[$page]['add'] ?? 0;
$allowDelete = $array[$page]['delete'] ?? 0;
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` providing like `/first.php` and `/second.php` but the `array` have `first.php` and `second.php`. Do you think it will work ??

Comment: @RakeshJakhar good point, I have updated. Note OP has the same problem in their code.

Comment: How can you know if the value of `$array[$page]['edit']` is '1' or '0'?

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj if `$array[$page]['edit']` is set, `$allowEdit` will get its value (regardless of whether it is 1 or 0). If it is not set, `$allowEdit` will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can `empty`

```
(!empty($array['1KEY']['2KEY'])) ? ($array['1KEY']['2KEY']) : '';
```